# Determining whether L is a linear map and finding the standard matrix for L

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}$

Show that $L: R^3 \rightarrow R^2$ by $L(\vec{w}) = \vec{v} \times \vec{w}$ 
is a linear map
and find the standard matrix for $L$.

Comment: want to share with us where are you stuck?

Comment: kinda have no clue how to approach it

Comment: T is linear iff T(v+cw) = T(v) + cT(w) for all v,w in the vector space and c in the field.

Comment: Then compute the transformation at the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and put it in the matrix

Comment: standard = at the canonical basis?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Verify that $L(\vec{w_1}+\vec{w_2})=L(\vec{w_1})+L(\vec{w_2})$ and $L(c\vec{w})=cL(\vec{w})$.

Also, compute $L(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit basis and $i \in \{1,2,3\}$. It is the vector with $1$ at the $i$-entry and $0$ otherwise.

The desired matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} L(e_1) & L(e_2) & L(e_3)\end{bmatrix}.$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\vec{u},\vec{w}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ we have to show that $L(\vec{u}+\lambda \vec{w}) = L(\vec{u}) + \lambda L(\vec{w})$, i.e., show that $(\vec{u}+\lambda \vec{w}) \times (1,2,3) = \vec{u} \times (1,2,3) ~+\lambda( \vec{w}\times \vec{v}) $, and you do this using the property of $\times$. Proving just this, you do the first part.

Then, by definition, for calculate the matrix of the transformation you just evaluate $L$ at some basis. How was said that "the standard matrix for $L$" this means calculate the matrix at the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, so you proceed like this: evaluate $L$ at each vector of the basis and then write each result in each column of the 3x3 matrix (you can do exactly like this just because we chose the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$), and then you're done.